# Using guards in Elixir macros

Tags: macros, elixir

I am working on macro which would take a function and add some additional functionality. Eg.:

This:

```
  defstate this_works(a, b) do
    a + b + 1
  end
```

Should be converted to this:

```
  def this_works(a, b) do
    IO.puts("LOGGING whatever")
    a + b + 1
  end
```

This is what I have so far. Try running this piece of code in iex:

```
  defmodule MyMacro do
    defmacro defstate(ast, do: block) do
      {fn_atom, _} = Macro.decompose_call(ast)

      quote do
        def unquote(fn_atom)(var!(a), var!(b)) do
          IO.puts("LOGGING")
          unquote(block)
        end
      end
    end
  end

  defmodule Test1 do
    import MyMacro

    defstate this_works(a, b) do
      a + b + 1
    end
  end

  Test.this_works(1, 2)
```

This works as expected.

Now, this module does not compile:

```
  defmodule Test2 do
    import MyMacro

    defstate this_fails(a, b) 
      when 1 < 2 
      when 2 < 3 
      when 3 < 4 do
      a + b + 1
    end
  end
```

The only change is that I added a guard and macro is unable to deal with that.

How can I improve `MyMacro.defstate` to make it work with a function with any number of guards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect `fn_atom` with the `defstate this_fails(a, b) when 1 < 2`, you'll see that it's `:when` instead of `:this_fails`. This is because of how `when` expressions are represented in the Elixir AST:

```
iex(1)> quote do
...(1)>   def foo, do: 1
...(1)> end
{:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [{:foo, [context: Elixir], Elixir}, [do: 1]]}
iex(2)> quote do
...(2)>   def foo when 1 < 2, do: 1
...(2)> end
{:def, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
 [{:when, [context: Elixir],
   [{:foo, [], Elixir}, {:<, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 2]}]},
  [do: 1]]}
```

You can fix this using some pattern matching:

```
defmodule MyMacro do
  defmacro defstate(ast, do: block) do
    f = case ast do
      {:when, _, [{f, _, _} | _]} -> f
      {f, _, _} -> f
    end

    quote do
      def unquote(ast) do
        IO.puts("LOGGING #{unquote(f)}")
        unquote(block)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  import MyMacro

  defstate this_works(a, b) do
    a + b + 1
  end

  defstate this_works_too(a, b) when a < 2 do
    a + b + 1
  end
end

defmodule A do
  def main do
    IO.inspect Test.this_works(1, 2)
    IO.inspect Test.this_works_too(1, 2)
    IO.inspect Test.this_works_too(3, 2)
  end
end

A.main
```

Output:

```
LOGGING this_works
4
LOGGING this_works_too
4
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Test.this_works_too/2

    The following arguments were given to Test.this_works_too/2:

        # 1
        3

        # 2
        2

    a.exs:24: Test.this_works_too/2
    a.exs:33: A.main/0
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:376: Code.require_file/2
```

(I also changed the unquote after `def` to make sure the `when` clause is preserved.)

Comment: Your answer is better :)

Comment: This is almost good. However my question was how to make this macro work with a function with *any* number of guards :) I can do some sophisticated recursive pattern matching on result of `Macro.decompose_call(ast)`. However I am looking for easier and simpler way of achieving that

Comment: What do you mean by "any number of guards"? A function can only have 1 guard.

Comment: @whysoserious the above would work perfectly for it and you might check this yourself. Second `when` is an alias for `and`.

Comment: Yes! Works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @mudasobwa Just a clarification, second `when` is an alias for `or` (which is weird for me).

Comment: @whysoserious indeed; that is why I never had it used and never will have it used.

Comment: (I didn't even know you could add multiple `when`!)

Answer (score 0):

The call to `defstate` is expanded at compile time to the things in the `quote` block from your `defmacro`. As such, guard expressions will not be applied to the macro call directly, because at compile time, the function you're defining inside is not called.

So you have to grab the `:when` tuple yourself and add the guards yourself:

```
defmodule MyMacro do
  defmacro defstate({:when, _, [ast, guards]}, do: block) do
    {fn_atom, _} = Macro.decompose_call(ast)

    quote do
      def unquote(fn_atom)(var!(a), var!(b)) when unquote(guards) do
        IO.puts("LOGGING")
        unquote(block)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Note how I match for a `{:when, _, [ast, guards]}` tuple now.

When you call a macro with a guard, it will put the original ast inside the first item of the arguments list, and the guard expression inside the second item.

Note that you'll still have to define a catch-all macro definition below this one in case you want to use your macro without guard clauses.